# Why is the equation $u_t + (a u)_x = 0$ conservative but $u_t + a u_x = 0$ isn't?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the following advection equations:
$$u_t + a u_x = 0$$

$$u_t + (au)_x = 0$$

I have heard the second one described as being conservative, yet the first one isn't. Why is this?

Comment: Notice your question and the title have different definitions of conservative!

Comment: @AloneAndConfused I don't see what you mean?

Comment: Looks like it was corrected by @stefano (see the edit history)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Physically speaking, ''conservative'' means that the total mass of $u$ is conserved in time. To see this, suppose $u : [0,T] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ with $u(t,0) = u(t,1)=0$ for all $t \in [0,T]$ and define the mass of $u$ at time $t$ by

$$M(t)= \int_0^1 u(t,x)dx.$$

If $u$ satisfies the second (conservative) equation, you get

$$ M'(t) = \int_0^1 \partial_t u(t,x)dx = -\int_0^1 \partial_x(a(t,x)u(t,x))dx = u(t,0)a(t,0)-u(t,1)a(t,1) = 0$$

Therefore the mass of $u$ is constant in time, so $u$ is conserved. In the first equation things go wrong because you get, after an integration by parts

$$M'(t) = -\int_0^1 a(t,x) \partial_x u(t,x)dx = \int_0^1 u(t,x) \partial_x a(t,x)dx + u(t,0)a(t,0)-u(t,1)a(t,1)$$

$$= \int_0^1 u(t,x) \partial_x a(t,x)dx.$$

and so $M$ is in general not constant in time: equation non conservative.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, as @Stefano has shown, writing a PDE in conservative form leads to something being constant in time, specifically an integral. It can be shown (and I am happy to do this if you wish), that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} F(t,x)\,dx \;=\; \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\left[ \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\phantom{\frac{}{}} F(t,x)v(t,x)\,\right)\right]\,dx$$

where $v(t,x)=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ is the instantaneous velocity. Clearly if the term under the integral on the right-hand side vanishes, then the integral on the left-hand side is constant in time. This is just a one-dimensional version of the more general [Reynold's transport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem). The joy of putting PDEs in conservative form (if it can be done) is that this integral form allows for discontinuous solutions (like shocks), whereas non-conservative PDEs only admit smooth solutions.